# How to get a second System.Thread.ThreadPool?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, threadpool, nested

If I use the ThreadPool in a nested way, my application hangs:

```
 ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) =>
      ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Action));
```

How to get a second and independent ThreadPool to achieve nesting?

Comment: why are you nesting a thread pool?

Comment: That should not cause your program to hang.  You probably have some other problem.

Comment: By the way this issue is called 'thread-starvation deadlock'. It is an inherent danger of the .NET thread pool and is described at chapter 'deadlock' in [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973903.aspx).

Comment: ...and also in [this article](http://dotnetdebug.net/2005/07/17/threadpool-deadlocks-avoid-drowning-yourself/).

Comment: One "problem" with the default/singleton thread-pool is it does not allow thread allocations for different components of a program - the MinThreads/MaxThreads are global. For a program with many threads (or even more simply, for many tasks) for different components with distinct characteristics in a process it simply doesn't allow the configuration necessary. While, arguably, this indicates there might be too much in a process, it doesn't fix the limitation.

Comment: Most ThreadPool-related issues I've run into have been related to unbound growth of things (*cough* Tasks *cough*) that attempt to use the thread-pool. Maximum concurrency control (sadly lacking from Tasks, available in most TPL) is very important for overall program stability: granted, there is always the case of a dead-lock if "needing one more thread than can be created" which is really a program design issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is only one single ThreadPool - it's not something you can (or should) make more than one instance of in an application.

I don't recommend doing this, but if you really wanted to, you could use multiple instances of your own ThreadPool implementation, such as [SmartThreadPool](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/smartthreadpool.aspx).  This would, technically, allow separate "thread pools".

However, I suspect you're hanging due to a [deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock), not due to the ThreadPool usage.  I would investigate where you're getting the hangs.  The VS2010 concurrency visualizer is very nice for this, if you have a copy of the VS 2010 beta installed.

Comment: Chosen because of the second paragraph

Comment: "it's not something you can (or should) make more than one instance of in an application." Bollucks! I do this all of the time in the JAVA world. It is very common to have a thread pool per system module or task. Spring Integration does this for example, for its pollers and adapters via an executor.

Answer (score 4):

Your application is probably hanging because you are filling it up to the point where all of the active threads are waiting on queued threads. (I assume the original thread is waiting for the work item(s) it queues to complete.)

The ThreadPool has by default 25 * (number of CPUs) worker threads (IIRC).

You probably want to rework the way you're queuing items. If you're queuing them up and then finishing and exiting the thread, you're fine, but having work items hanging around waiting on other processes is generally a bad design; if that's what you're doing you probably need to use real threads or a completely different design. Using real threads is probably an equally bad idea because all that will do (based on what I can surmise of your usage) you'll just create a large number of threads, which will do nothing good for your performance.

A better design might be to have some kind of queue or stack that a few (2-4 depending on number of CPUs) worker threads add items to and pop items off to work. If an item needs to queue a new item it just adds it to the stack (and adds itself back to the stack with some kind of dependency tracking if it needs to wait for the other item).

Comment: It would be interesting to get a definitive number of threads per threadpool. I've seen it somewhere, just can't recall where. Anyway, I would create a new threadpool rather than trying to manhandle the threadpool into a queue - just keep a collection of the instanced threadpools (array, list, dict).

Comment: @dboarman you can actually set the threadpool size using the static methods on ThreadPool

Comment: I agree. You should look at your worker threads to see if there's shared objects that could cause a deadlock, and revisit your architecture to realign your thread "boundaries."

Comment: @dboarman I'm not suggesting "manhandling". If he's got tasks that need to execute other tasks recursively, then a stack or queue (depending on execution semantics) is probably the cleanest way to handle it. Allowing a thread explosion (threads creating threads creating threads) is just going to cause performance issues, whether it's in a threadpool or via System.Threading.Threads.

Comment: @technophile: sorry, I wasn't clear - my comment was directed towards the OP on manhandling. It seems like nesting them would be the worst kind of coercion.

Comment: @Rob: I know you can increase the size of the ThreadPool - honestly I was wondering why the OP doesn't simply do that. If a new threadpool is the only way to get an implementation solved, then so be it.

Comment: Increasing the size of the threadpool is more likely to (usually only slightly) delay the problem than solve it, in my experience.

Comment: @dboarman @technophile i'm with technophile. There must be a way to do this that isn't deadlock-prone instead

Comment: roger roger, first thing would to not nest threadpools... if .Net 4.0 is not an option (which is quite likely), the OP should start out with only a handful (say 5) threads. If more are needed then spin one up - up to say a max of 10. The OP can still use the ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem when one of the threads has gone idle. Does this sound right?

Comment: I would probably just spin up say 2xCPUs number of WorkItem threads and have them never exit, and then use one or more queues/stacks to manage their workload. That assumes workload is pretty steady; if this is a situation where the need for background tasks is rare or unpredictable you might do it differently. OTOH, if this is the major purpose of the app, though, I might look at using something like Windows Workflow Foundation instead.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong tools.

In .NET 4.0 they introduced the Task Parallel Library. This allows you to do things like use multiple thead pools as well as have parent-child relationships between work items.

Start with the Task class, which replaces ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(VS.100).aspx

**EDIT**

Example of creating your own thread pool using Task and TaskScheduler.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997413(VS.100).aspx

Comment: This is not technically correct.  The TPL is built upon the .NET ThreadPool - it does NOT create multiple thread pools, but rather, uses the (improved) ThreadPool in the framework for scheduling of tasks.

Comment: The TaskScheduler in Task.Start(TaskScheduler) is abstract, so you can construct your thread pools anyway you want.

Comment: The choice of framework or tools is the OP's to make, and the brief code snippet shown does not provide enough context for us to judge whether using `ThreadPool` directly, or indirectly via the TPL, is appropriate or not.

Comment: He can choose any tool he wants, but to the best of my ability I'm going to suggest the correct tool.

Comment: Last I checked, ThreadPool has been rewritten to sit on top of TPL rather than the other way around. That's because TPL offers other advantages such as work-stealing queues.

Answer (score 1):

While the [Windows API allows for multiple Thread Pools in a process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686760(v=vs.85).aspx), .NET does not *directly* expose this. In the .NET Framework..

***There is Exactly One .NET ThreadPool per .NET AppDomain***, and absolutely no way to change this.

So with different application domains.. it is possible to have different .NET ThreadPools within the same process.

(NOTE: The heuristics for the Hill Climb algorithm used in .NET is also determined on a per-.NET ThreadPool basis. This, along *without* being able to specify a maximum number of workers per type, is a downside of a 'global per appdomain' ThreadPool with varied workloads.)

Answer (score 0):

There is one and only one threadpool.

Comment: Well, technically, there's one per *process* (or one per AppDomain, I'm not sure), so you *could* get multiples involved. It just seems like a really bad idea. :)

Comment: True.  This particular implementation appeared to be confined to a single process.

Answer (score -1):

One way is using BlockingCollection.
This is the class i build for it:

**Updated at 2018-04-23:**

```
public class WorkerPool<T> : IDisposable
{
    BlockingCollection<T> queue = new BlockingCollection<T>();
    List<Task> taskList;
    private CancellationTokenSource cancellationToken;
    int maxWorkers;
    private bool wasShutDown;

    int waitingUnits;

    public WorkerPool(CancellationTokenSource cancellationToken, int maxWorkers)
    {
        this.cancellationToken = cancellationToken;
        this.maxWorkers = maxWorkers;
        this.taskList = new List<Task>();
    }
    public void enqueue(T value)
    {
        queue.Add(value);
        waitingUnits++;
    }
    //call to signal that there are no more item
    public void CompleteAdding()
    {
        queue.CompleteAdding();          
    }

    //create workers and put then running
    public void startWorkers(Action<T> worker)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxWorkers; i++)
        {
            taskList.Add(new Task(() =>
            {
                string myname = "worker " + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                try
                {
                    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {                     
                        var value = queue.Take();
                        waitingUnits--;
                        worker(value);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex) when (ex is InvalidOperationException)  //throw when collection is closed with  CompleteAdding method. No pretty way to do this.
                {
                    //do nothing
                }
            }));
        }

        foreach (var task in taskList)
        {
            task.Start();
        }
    }

    //wait for all workers to be finish their jobs
    public void await()
    {
        while (waitingUnits >0 || !queue.IsAddingCompleted)
            Thread.Sleep(100);

        shutdown();
    }

    private void shutdown()
    {
        wasShutDown = true;
        Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());            
    }

    //case something bad happen dismiss all pending work
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!wasShutDown)
        {
            queue.CompleteAdding();
            shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

To see it working build this unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void workerPoolTest()
{
    WorkerPool<int> workerPool = new WorkerPool<int>(new CancellationTokenSource(), 5);

    workerPool.startWorkers(value =>
    {
        log.Debug(value);
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        workerPool.enqueue(i);
    }
    workerPool.CompleteAdding();
    workerPool.await();
}
```

**Now you can have as many polls has you like, just by creating new WorkPool objects.**

Note that the code is not fully tested.